# Play Service wont submit score

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

Im running into a problem when trying to submit a score to my Play Services Leader board. From my MainActivity the user is logged in successfully then from my GameScreen activity I try to submit a score  but it fails:(...My Question is does the connection persist or do I have to reconnect the user before I submit???

MAIN ACTIVITY.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements View.OnClickListener,      GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

Button siButton;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();

    siButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
    siButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
                signOut();
                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });    
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

GAMESCREEN

```
public class GameScreen extends BaseGameActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private int c;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
TextView counter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);
    setRequestedClients(BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_GAMES | BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_APPSTATE);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();



private void progressSetup() {
    Thread timerThread = new
            Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (mbActive && (waited < TIMER_RUNTIME)) {
                            sleep(THREAD_SLEEP);
                            if (mbActive) {
                                waited += 100;
                                updateProgress(waited);
                                if (waited > 9999) {
                                    mbActive = false;
                                    gameOver();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d("fail", "failure" + e);
                    }
                }
            };
    startTread = false;
    timerThread.start();
}

private void updateProgress(final int timePassed) {
    if (null != mProgressBar) {
        progress = mProgressBar.getMax() * timePassed / TIMER_RUNTIME;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}

//game over
private void gameOver() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            upDateScore();
        }
    });
}

private void upDateScore(){
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.app_id), c);
        Log.d("connectted.....................................................");
    } else {          
        Log.d("not connectted.....................................................");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent home = new Intent(GameScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(home);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just replace getString(R.string.app_id) with your LEADERBOARD id in method Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.app_id).

Leaderboard id looks like this: "CgkI0tXt-q0HEA****"

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Syabro is right. You must use the LEADERBOARD_ID, see [Leaderboards in Android - Updating the player's score](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards).

In the developer console's game services section, you can easily export your leaderboard and achievements ids as xml files using the provided button.

In general, using the game services with more than one activity might cause additional waiting periods as each of them signs in individually at its start. Therefore, as far as I know, the implementation with fragments should be preferred, see this famous example [playgameservices/android-basic-samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/TypeANumber/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tanc).